# Filter array datas by inserting/updating values with JS

Tags: javascript, object

I've the following object in JS:

```
[{date: "2019-03-10", roomid: 48, status: "Open"}, {date: "2019-03-11", roomid: 47, status: "Open"}, {date: "2019-03-20", roomid: 48, status: "Book"}]
```

How can I check :

- if the values `roomid` and `date` already exist, update the `status`.
- if the values `roomid` and `date` doesn't exist, push new datas.

-

What I have tried:

```
arr = arr.filter(a => a.date != $(this).data('date') && a.roomid != $(this).data('roomid'));
arr.push({
    date: date,
    roomid : roomid,
    status : updatedStatus
});
```

I'm comparing this object with clicks on severals `div`:

```
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>

var status = $(this).data('status');
var date   = $(this).data('date');
var roomid = $(this).data('roomid');
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you know why ?

Comment: you compare object with what?

Comment: Use `Set` rather than array. The Set API supports your use case directly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Set_instances

Comment: @Ehsan: code updated.

Comment: Ok what you are doing in your code is overriding the value of your array with the result of the filter function (so i will have a subset of the original values) and then pushing new data...that is no what you described you wanted.

Comment: @dwaksman it sounds like what i would like.

Answer (score 0):

Sets would be a better choice but if you must use arrays you can use a function to pinpoint the index the object and then just use that index to update or push new data. 
The following function is taken as is from lodash repo on github here: https://github.com/lodash/

```
function findIndex(array, predicate, fromIndex) {
   var length = array == null ? 0 : array.length;
   if (!length) {
      return -1;
   }
   var index = fromIndex == null ? 0 : toInteger(fromIndex);
   if (index < 0) {
      index = nativeMax(length + index, 0);
   }
   return baseFindIndex(array, getIteratee(predicate, 3), index);
}
```

What I would do is:

```
let idx = findIndex( arr, a => {
   return (a.date != $(this).data('date') && a.roomid != $(this).data('roomid'));
})

if (idx != -1) {
   //update
   arr[idx].status = "new status"
}

else {
   //push new
   arr.push({
    date: date,
    roomid : roomid,
    status : updatedStatus
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the dates as the same object type. Rather than have "a => a.date" make both parts of the argument as date objects and then use the valueOf() function.

```
var date1 = new Date(a.date);
```

then check them as

```
if (date1.valueOf() => date2.valueOf()) // do something
```